# Creating custom notification with xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android

I have been trying to make a fully custom notification with Xamarin.android.
My project targets min API of 14, so expended notification are supported. I'm trying to achieve the same look for all API's so i'm using `Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.Builder`.

I have found out that you can use [setCustomContentView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)) to set a custom View that will change the layout of the notification complitly, which is what i aim for.

Here is the code that i have tried to run:

```
RemoteViews widgetLayout = new RemoteViews(PackageName,Resource.Layout.SingleNotificationLayout);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .SetCustomBigContentView(widgetLayout);

notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder.Build());
```

Which `Resource.Layout.SingleNotificationLayout` is a layout file for the notification.Im running this code from `MainActiviy`.Code is modified from [here](https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-n-introducing-upgraded-notifications-d4dd98a7ca92#.uyrg3fejh).

The error that i'm facing is that `SetCustomBigContentView` is not found, specifically :

```
'NotificationCompat.Builder' does not contain a definition for 'SetCustomBigContentView' and no extension method 'SetCustomBigContentView' accepting a first argument of type 'NotificationCompat.Builder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Here are my installed packages:

```
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v14.Preference" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.GridLayout" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Preference" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
```

What am i missing ? Is the equivalent function named differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the latest pre-release packages for the support libraries. Specifically https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/24.2.1-rc1 which includes a new assembly: `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat`. This will include the method you're looking for:

**EX: Looking through `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` in DotPeek**

[image]

However it's not included in the current stable(23.4.0.1) as you can see here:

**EX: Looking through `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` in DotPeek**

[image]