# How can actions be implemented in local notifications in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, notifications, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am developing an Xamarin.Forms app for Android and iOS, that requires me to implement local notifications. I have done this using the Local Notifications Plugin for Xamarin and Windows, https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin and it works fine. I get the notifications as I am supposed to, but I was wondering if there is a way to add actions/commands to this, type 'buttons' for accept/decline, like you can do in pop-up and dialogs. I don't know if this can be done using the plugin I am currently using, or if there is another plugin or something else that I can use instead.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can custom the notification's layout to achieve your goal.

I have found some links for you, this is about [how to Create Custom Notification Layout](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97978/how-to-create-custom-notification-layout), and here is [creating custom notification with xamarin.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045499/creating-custom-notification-with-xamarin-android)
.

As you can see, on Android, the notification's layout is [RemoteViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews), it is not a normal view,you need [`setCustomContentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setCustomContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)) method for you notification.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way for having it more xamarin based, a plugin or something like that, so I don't have to write separate code for android and iOS?

Comment: I haven't found one. Have you found it?